# C++ dll in hololens

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens

I am working creating a hololens application using a native code dll based on c ++. The problem comes when I add it in the unity project (plugins / WSA / x86).

When generating the UWP solution in Visual Studio I get a failure of DllNotFound.

From what I have been able to read, it is necessary to create a UWP library to use it in my application. That library must contain my native code. The truth is that I'm not sure how to do that. Is there any way to stop my dll based on c ++ on a UWP dll ??

> error: System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'nativoHololensPrueba.dll': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

[image]

**C++**

```
SOURCE:
  #include <iostream>
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <memory>
  #include "Header.h"

__declspec(dllexport)
int testo() {
return 10;
}

HEADER:
extern "C" {

__declspec(dllexport)
    int testo();
}
```

**c#**

```
[DllImport("nativoHololensPrueba")]
public static extern int testo();

// Use this for initialization

public GameObject texto;


void Start () {
    texto.GetComponent<TextMesh>().text = "Cambiando el nombre " + testo();
}
```

[image]

Comment: The right way to do this and actually receive a useful answer is to: 1. Provide a screenshot of the folder you put the dll file. This will help us verify that you got the folder spellings and path right. 2.Write a simple C# and C++ function  then try to call that function. Post both the simple C# and C++ function here to verify that you used the correct DllImport. 3.When you receive an error, post it like it is. Don't changing it into your own word .You may be surprised that by googling that error, you'll find your solution.

Comment: I see your update. Is this managed or unmanaged C++ plugin?

Comment: sorry, i´m new in this. what is the difference?

Comment: You can just google "managed or unmanaged C++". I assume it is unmanaged based on your code and I hope I am right. I haven't made Hololens C++ plugin so I can't tell the issue yet but provide the second parameter in the `DllImport` function and see what happens. `[DllImport("nativoHololensPrueba", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]`

Comment: it returns me the same error, i add the error screenshot

Comment: Ok. The C++ code, does it have both .cpp or and .h files or just the .cpp file?

Comment: both (I add the header code)

Comment: I find so many issues and can't tell which one is causing it. You need to fix each one I point out to you and also update your question with it if it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to put the function that is in the header inside `extern "C"
{ your function }`to avoid name mangling.

Comment: in header and source?

Comment: *"the function that is in the header"*

Comment: I add extern "C"{} in source function. and it returns me the same problem.
extern "C" {
 __declspec(dllexport)
  int testo() {
  return 10;
 }
}

Comment: I'm also facing this problem. Did you solve it yet?

Comment: You solved this?

Comment: I generate a native library (DLL) and introduce in plugins in a WSA file. then use dllImport(...)

Comment: Could you please give a detailed description of how you solve this? I have the same problem

Comment: I have a program with a c ++ code using Visual Studio. Within the functions in c ++ I generate a dllexport attribute to the functions that I am going to export for unity.
Subsequently, I generate the libraries in Release and insert them in the plugins / WSA folder.
In the C # section I create an attribute at the beginning the code with export functions in c ++ using the dllimport command.

Comment: All your libraries AND dependencies must target same architecture - Hololens1 = x86, Hololens2 = ARM/ARM64. Then in Unity Editor you must configure them separately for each platform (WSAPlayer for both Hololens1 and 2)

Answer (score 1):

I also had this and I solved it by compiling the dll on ARM64 (or ARM) with /MT flag.